# Gallery software for a website that will resize based on height, with a click on image to navigate

Tags: javascript, css, flash, gallery, photo-gallery

I was looking at this gallery:
http://www.orangegirlphotographs.com/portfolio.cfm?galleryID=4

And just loved the way it looked, anyone have any idea how to get a similar effect using ideally CSS/JS and if not then using flash? Furthermore it would be excellent if you could move to the next slide by clicking on the image itself.

I'm also wondering how she is able to maintain height of the images when resizing (unless she is doing it manually which I doubt now days).

I normally use Gallery3 for my image uploading, automatic resizing with AnotherSlider to get a sliding effect but I would really appreciate it if you guys could direct me to something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's probably your best bet here. I've used the Cycle plugin with slideshows before: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Look at the examples and you'll get an idea of what it can do: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23

For the height, either all the images have the same height, or simply setting it in html will keep the ratio. It's better to have them all the same height and resize them in something like Photoshop as the results will be smoother

Comment: The Cycle plugin is fantastic, I've used it before but didn't know you could create external navigation links!

Comment: yeah, i only know about it cause i used it the other day :D